# Gearhead Speed bonus calculation

Tags: shadowrun-sr5

How does the Speed +20% bonus from Gearhead Quality works? Should I sum up this with the Speed Attribute or should I just adjust the speed movement value?

For example: my car has Speed 3. If I choose to improve Speed, should I calculate 3+20% or just adjust my movement speeds with the vehicle to 24/48 m/turn? If I should calculate 3+20%, should I round up the value?

Additionally, Gearhead gives an extra +1 modifier to Speed or Handling that lasts for 1D6 minutes. If I'm using that +20% bonus, should I calculate this *after* applying this +1 modifier? Or before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because CGL has been having issues with reusing terms and generally providing some (what I consider to be) poor quality explanations, especially in complex areas like vehicles, it's hard for me to provide a RAW answer. Instead, I will give you my judgement as a GM.

## The +20% Speed bonus is applied to the Movement Rates Table on pg. 202

First, you state:

> Gearhead gives an extra +1 modifier to Speed or Handling

It only provides a +1 modifier to Handling. When the book states:

> a Gearhead can increase the Speed of her vehicle or drone by 20 percent

I interpret that to mean the distance table provided for the different Speed ratings. Better wording by CGL could have made that clearer. It doesn't make sense to apply to the actual Speed rating of the vehicle, as nowhere else that I can find is there a percentage change to stats.

So, if your vehicle has a Speed of 3 and you opt for the 20% bonus, it can now move 24/48 M/Turn.

The rest of your questions should be moot given the above decision.

Comment: Interesting. I'm using a brazilian portuguese version of the book and it states that you can choose between Speed/Handling to use that +1 modifier for 1D6 minutes. I think there is an error in the translation. Anyway, I think you answer makes sense.

Comment: @BrunoEstrazulas Yeah, that would indeed change things up. It's very interesting they state Speed/Handling, but I'm willing to be that was an editorial oversight. Unfortunately that's been common in recent releases.